# How can I concatenate two equally structured JSON datasets in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code which calls two different API's, parses the JSON data and displays it on a webpage. Both JSON datasets have the same structure, one with 5 columns and the other one with 20 columns.

The JavaScript code I am using is shown below. How can I combine both JSON datasets into one, so there's a resulting dataset with 25 columns, enabling me to search/reference across all those 25 columns?

**The Data Structure of both JSON datasets is as follows:**

```js
{
"datatable": {
        "data": [
                  [
                    "TSLA",
                    "2019-02-22",
                    "2019-02-22",
                    58995.9,
                    -231.2
                  ]
                ],
         "columns": [
                {
                    "name": "ticker",
                    "type": "String"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "date",
                    "type": "Date"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "lastupdated",
                    "type": "Date"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "ev",
                    "type": "BigDecimal(15,3)"
                 },
                 {
                    "name": "evebit",
                    "type": "BigDecimal(15,3)"
                    }
                 ]
},
"meta": {
                    "next_cursor_id": null
        }
}
```

**The JavaScript Code is as follows:**

```js
var apiurls = [
    'api1.json',
    'api2.json'
  ],
  elroot = document.getElementById('root'),
  index = 0;

function setup() {
  loadJSON(apiurls[index], gotData);
}

function gotData(data) {
  var daten = data.datatable.data[0],
    spalten = data.datatable.columns,
    output = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < spalten.length; i++) {
    output = '<p>' + spalten[i].name + ': ' + daten[i] + '</p>';
    elroot.innerHTML += output;
  }
  if (++index < apiurls.length) {
    setup();
  }
}
```

Comment: not understood. no need to say where the information comes from if it is not the problem. Just give an example of the 2 json files that must be accumulated?

Comment: It's considered good style to indent your code. Doing so makes it easier to discern the structure of your code, even in something as simple as json. An even better question might involve the sample inputs, and a sample output, so that someone else only has to worry about the transformation.

Comment: @Joshua Thank you for the helpful guidance, I am still learning and will do my best to be more precise and provide the samples you mentioned. Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to make all the API calls first, combining them into a single result object before doing any processing. Currently, you are making an API call, then processing the results before making the next API call.

I think the nature of async callbacks is making your task more difficult. I suggest using async/await to simplify the logic. Something like this:

```
var apiurls = [
    'api1.json',
    'api2.json'
  ],
  elroot = document.getElementById('root');

// Combine all API responses into this object
allResults = {
  data: [[]],
  columns: []
};


// loadJSON() is probably not async, so here is an async version using fetch()
async function loadJSON(url) {
  response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json()
}

// Wrap logic in async function so await can be used
(async () => {
    // First make all the API calls
    for (url of apiurls) {
        results = await loadJSON(url);
        allResults.data[0] = allResults.data[0].concat(results.datatable.data[0]);
        allResults.columns = allResults.columns.concat(results.datatable.columns);
    }

    // Then process combined allResults object here once.
    var daten = allResults.data[0],
        spalten = allResults.columns,
        output = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < spalten.length; i++) {
        output = '<p>' + spalten[i].name + ': ' + daten[i] + '</p>';
        elroot.innerHTML += output;
    }
})();
```

The `loadJSON()` you are using probably isn't async. Here are some alternatives you can use:

- [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: Hi @Leftium, I like this improved approach. Yes, the `await` doesn't combine with the `loadJSON()`. Where and how exactly do I insert the `fetch()` code example you provided?

Comment: There was an async version of loadJSON at the end of my answer; I updated my answer to include it in my answer's main code. Instead of wrapping it in loadJSON(), you can also just call the fetch() method directly. `await` can only be used inside async functions, so you may have to wrap all the logic inside an async function, too.

Comment: Thanks. The line `results = await loadJSON(url);`causes the following error message in the console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: @F.Marks: Yes, that is the error I mentioned in my previous comment. I updated the answer with logic wrapped in async function. Note that any code after this async block might happen "out of order" compared to the way you might expect. This is because the async function is executed asynchronously. So just make sure everything you want to happen after the API calls is inside this new async function.

Comment: There's no error but something is not working, as there's no output on the webpage. `console.log(spalten.length);` returns a 0. I think it is the JSON structure, I saw there's a difference between the columns and data structure. See updated JSON above.

Comment: @F.Marks: There was a problem with my code because concat() does not modify the original array. I fixed it by adding the required assignment. Also the `data` property had an unexpected nested array structure; I updated the code so it will also handle that structure properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188948/discussion-between-leftium-and-f-marks).

Answer (score 2):

something like that ?

```js
var
  Json_1 = {
    "datatable": {
      "data"   : ['aa','bb','cc'],
      "columns": ['x','y','z']
    },
    "meta": { 'meta1': 15, 'meta2':87 }
  },
  Json_2 = {
    "datatable": {
      "data"   : ['ZZbb','cZc'],
      "columns": ['xf','yf','zf','zgg']
    },
    "meta":  { 'meta1': 879, 'meta2':4 }
  },

  Json_cumul_typ0 = { Json_1, Json_2   },
  Json_cumul_typ1 = {
    "data"   : [].concat( Json_1.datatable.data, Json_2.datatable.data ),
    "columns": [].concat( Json_1.datatable.columns, Json_2.datatable.columns ),
  }
  
;

console.log( Json_cumul_typ0 );

console.log( Json_cumul_typ1 );
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how the JSON data is structured. Please apologize if I wasn't specific enough with my question, I will try to be more precise next time.

Comment: @Joshua, the answer doesn't work yet as it is not precise enough, at least not considering my JavaScript knowledge level. I do not understand how to implement that in my concrete code example which I gave above.

Answer (score 1):

```
var object1 = {
    "datatable": {
        "data": [],
        "columns": [1,2,3,4]
    },
    "meta": {}
}
var object2 = {
    "datatable": {
        "data": [],
        "columns": [6,7,8,9,0,11,12,123]
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

Now you want to concatenate columns field. So what you can do is create a deep copy of one of the above. There are better ways to do this than the one mentioned below.

```
var object3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object1));
```

Now to concatenate columns do this,

`object3.datatable.columns = object3.datatable.columns.concatenate(object2.datatable.columns);`

If you want to concatenate multiple fields you can use a for loop on an object, check if the data type is an array and do the concatenation.

I hope this helps.